# MYSQL LIKE to match part of a string

Tags: php, mysql

I have a query but just can not seem to get this to work.

Here is what i am speicificallly looking for inside a mysql table string

**link =** index.php?option=com_content&view=article&layout=custom:article&id=13

I need to do a MYSQL query that matches view=article so i can exclude rows that have that.

```
SELECT * FROM menus WHERE published=1 AND link LIKE '\view=\article\%'
```

Thnak you so much in advance

more updated code:

```
<field 
class="menuselections" 
name="bannerpage" 
type="sql" 
default="" 
label="Show On Menus" 
query="SELECT * FROM #__menu WHERE published=1 AND link LIKE '%\view=\article\%' AND title NOT IN('Menu_item_Root','com_joomlaupdate')" 
key_field="id" 
value_field="title" 
multiple="true" />
```

Comment: `link NOT LIKE '%view=article%'` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need wildcards on both ends of the string, given the example.

```
SELECT * FROM menus WHERE published=1 AND link LIKE '%view=article%'
```

However, since you said you want to EXCLUDE them, use NOT LIKE instead.

Comment: i dont know why but its not wokring

Comment: Credit to jessica as her post was first and i actually worked out teh NOT LIKE before coming back her. Thanks to everyone. Its so easy but so helpfull to my banner manager in joomla. Clients can now display a banner block on an article or menu in avery easy way without having to learn how joomla modules work.

Answer (score 4):

I don't have enough reputation points to comment on Jessica's answer, which is basically correct.  The only change I would suggest to it is to remove the backslashes from the like clause (and keep the leading wildcard '%' character):

```
SELECT * FROM menus WHERE published=1 AND link LIKE '%view=article%';
```

Backslashes are for escaping characters in a string, which isn't what you are trying to do in this case.